# wsdl2java has missing package error in java code

Tags: java, wsdl, axis

I'm trying to test the axis2 eclipse plugin, but once I generate a wsdl -> java, it creates java code but with numerous errors (primarily missing packages).

For instance, the following wsdl:
http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL

will produce java code, but method calls associated with packages such as:

```
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean
```

will produce an error saying that it is missing.
I was wondering how I can fix this problem, thanks.

axis2 plugin: v1.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Axis2 JARs are probably missing from your Eclipse project's classpath.

To add them, right-click on the project folder and select "Properties" from the context menu.  Navigate to "Java Build Path" and then click on the "Libraries" tab.  Add the Axis2 JARs by clicking on the "Add JARs..." button.

Comment: @bigbitecode bigbitecode I said click on the "Libraries" **tab**, not the Libraries button...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using netbeans for this? From what I remember it had much better support for web services class generation.

You can start here : http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

Comment: Is there a particular tool or service that netbeans offers that helps this process?

Comment: @bigbitecode that's the thing it works out of the box. Just search online there are a lot of tutorials on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing `axis2-adb-1.6.2.jar` from your classpath.